# I want to display social security number like this xxx-xx-**** last four digits we have to hide while entering the key

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery code

```
   $('#ssn1').keyup(function() {
      var val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
      var newVal = '';
      if(val.length > 4) {
         this.value = val;
      }
      if((val.length > 3) && (val.length < 6)) {
         newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
         val = val.substr(3);
      }
      if (val.length > 5) {
         newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
         newVal += val.substr(3, 2) + '-';
         val = val.substr(5);
       }
       newVal += val;
       this.value = newVal.substring(0, 11);
    });
```

Please help me how to hide last four digits and store in database like password,Please give me some edit for this code.Thanks in Advance.but retain the value in the field.

Comment: Shouldn't you hide the first five numbers instead?

Comment: No sir, i want only hiding the last 4 digits

Comment: can u hide the first five digits?